# init function does not run before unit test golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, debugging

When debug in GoLand, I found `init` function run before some unit test, but not run before some unit test. I have not set any configuration related to unit test and `init` function. For example:

function A:

package1/function a()

function B:

package2/function b()

function C:

package3/int()

`init` runs before a(), but not befor b(). It's so weired. I have not found any law.

Comment: The order in which init functions are executed is deterministic and specified in the language spec. You might have to move them around.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests should test a single package. Packages that are not referred to (not imported) from the tested package may or may not be initialized, you should not assume anything about packages not imported.

You only have guarantees that `init()` functions of all imported packages will be called first (recursively). The rules are listed in [Spec: Package initialization](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization).

So if you test `packagea` which does not import `packageb`, there is no guarantee that `init()` functions of `packageb` will be run. If you need that, you have to import `packageb`.

See related question: [Is it really bad to use init in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56039154/is-it-really-bad-to-use-init-in-go/56039373#56039373)